# Why do edited jpgs get larger

Tags: jpeg, image-editing

OS: W10
Tool: Photos application

I normally scan in pictures away from the top right side of my scanner because of a scanner fault - it produces a lighter coloured line down the picture.  Anyway, after scanning, I edit the picture to remove the borders.

```
_______________________
|////|           |/////|
|////| Picture   |/////|  /// area removed
|////|           |/////|
|////|           |/////|
|//////////////////////|
```

The area removed is just white.  After scanning, the picture is about 700kB.  After removing the whitespace, this picture is 825kB.  I would have thought it would be smaller but it is larger.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You saved the image using the default value for Q, which affects the JPEG compression level and resulting file size.  Try saving with a lower value for Q.

Comment: I've looked at the photo editor.  I can't figure out how to change the value of Q.

Comment: *"I can't figure out how to change..."* -- Did you try RTM?

Comment: The only manual I can find is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/edit-photos-and-videos-in-windows-10-a3a6e711-1b70-250a-93fa-ef99048a2c86 but that doesn't talk about Q values.  Also did an internet search on changing Q values using the W10 photo editor.  Can't see anything.

Comment: The Q is only relevant when *saving* the image as a compressed JPEG file.  If there is no method to change/specify the quality factor when saving, then maybe you need to change to a more capable program.  Why you would want such flexibility: see https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30243/what-quality-to-choose-when-converting-to-jpg

Comment: @sawdust.  Thanks for the help.  Do you have enough rep to mark this as closed?